# What are "environment target actions" in Google AdWords HTML5 ads?

Tags: google, advertising, html5, google-ads, ad-targeting

[Google AdWords documentation for ad formats](https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/176108?hl=en#html5_ads_table) list several requirements for creating ads in HTML5.  One of the requirements is:

> For environment target actions, timer and multiple exits are not supported.

I understand what the other requirements mean, but I haven't been able to find any documentation for "environment target actions".  I'm creating a dynamic HTML5 ad for my website and I need to make sure that it complies with all these policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in reference to the Action tab inside the Events dialog. Take a look at this picture:

[image: Google Web Designer - Events Dialog - Action Tab - Google Ad]

Don't use those settings and you should be in the clear. This is straight from GWD team member:

> In the Events dialog of GWD, there is Google Ad section in the Action
>   tab. Some of the items don't work with AdWords environment such as
>   timer. Also if you set multiple exits the ad is not accepted.

Description:

**Timer**

A timer lets you measure the length of any action.

**Exit**

An exit is a click-through area in an ad.